# Trouble using TestUtils.Simulate to create a change event on an input element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, reactjs-testutils

I'm trying to write tests in jest for the examples shown in "Thinking in React" (http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html)

And I am having a hard time using TestUtils.Simulate to provide a change-event to the search input object.

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

jest.dontMock('../ProductTable.js');
jest.dontMock('../FilterableProductTable.js');
jest.dontMock('../SearchBar.js');
var React = require('react/addons');
var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;
var FilterableProductTable = require('../FilterableProductTable.js');
var SearchBar = require('../SearchBar.js');

var PRODUCTS = [
    {category: 'thing', name: 'glove', price: '$0.50', stocked: true},
    {category: 'thing', name: 'spam', price: '$1.50', stocked: true},
    {category: 'thing', name: 'glam', price: '$9.50', stocked: false},
    {category: 'thing', name: 'blam', price: '$99.00', stocked: true},
    {category: 'thing', name: 'sham', price: '$0.20', stocked: true},
];

describe('FilterableProductTable', function() {
    it('creates the entire table', function () {
        filterableProductTable = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
            <FilterableProductTable
                products={PRODUCTS}
                filterText = {''}
                inStockOnly = {false}
            />
        );
        var rows = TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(filterableProductTable, 'tr');
        expect(rows.length).toEqual(7); // 5 items and 2 headers
    });

    it('searches the table for proper stuff', function() {
        filterableProductTable = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
            <FilterableProductTable
                products={PRODUCTS}
                filterText = {''}
                inStockOnly = {false}
            />
        );
        // var inputBox = document.querySelectorAll('#search-box');
        // console.log(inputBox.innerHTML);
        var inputObjects = TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(filterableProductTable, 'input');
        var inputBox = inputObjects[0];
        // TestUtils.Simulate.keyUp(inputBox, {key: 'a'});
        TestUtils.Simulate.change(inputBox, {target: {value: 'a'}});
        var rows = TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(filterableProductTable, 'tr');
        expect(rows.length).toEqual(6); // FAILS. This is equal to 7 as in the previous test.
    });
});
```

Does anyone have a suggestion? Am I using Testutils.Simulate incorrectly?

Comment: Did you ever get this solved? I'm trying to do the same and the change event doesn't fire :( Looking at the React docs suggests that the change event is used correctly but it does nothing in Jest.

Comment: No, I have not ever gotten this to work.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem recently and simply did this:

```
React.findDOMNode(inputBox).value = 'a';
TestUtils.Simulate.change(inputBox);
```

I could not make Simulate or SimulateNative to change the value so just changed the value on the node manually then triggered a change event via Simulate.

One of the developers of React mentioned on github that they are currently testing the Simulate.change the same way (setting value manually then triggering change). 
I don't know why they have it in the manuals still (if I read it correctly it was working in 0.11 but broken since 0.12).